# Unable to save alsamixer settings on bookworm xfce

Tags: debian, xfce, settings, alsamixer

I'm french so thanks for forgiving my english
I'm on debian bookworm xfce and I'm unable to save alsamixer Headphons settings.
When I start a session there is no sound,  the command

```
alsamixer
```

always shows Headphons on mute MM. Automute is always disabled
Then I run

```
sudo alsactl init
```

and the sound comes back, trouble is that this setting is not saved by

```
sudo alsactl store
```

( sudo alsactl restore doesn't work) so I must repeat

```
sudo alsactl init
```

each time I reboot or each time I awake my PC
Here are some results :

```
joel@hP600:~$ sudo systemctl --no-p status alsa-{state,restore} 
[sudo] Mot de passe de joel :  
○ alsa-state.service - Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-state.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
  Condition: start condition failed at Sat 2024-01-06 09:42:55 CET; 9h ago
             └─ ConditionPathExists=/etc/alsa/state-daemon.conf was not met
       Docs: man:alsactl(1)

janv. 06 09:42:55 hP600 systemd[1]: alsa-state.service - Manage Sound
Card …nf).

● alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service; static)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2024-01-06 09:42:55 CET; 9h ago
       Docs: man:alsactl(1)
    Process: 660 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore (code=exited,
status=0/SUCCESS)    
   Main PID: 660 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 3ms

janv. 06 09:42:55 hP600 systemd[1]: Starting alsa-restore.service - Save/Re…e... 
janv. 06 09:42:55 hP600 systemd[1]: Finished alsa-restore.service - Save/Re…ate. 
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full. 
joel@hP600:~$

joel@hP600:~$ sudo alsactl init
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Conexant CX20952" "HDA:14f151d7,103c82b5,00100000 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x103c" "0x82b5"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method 
joel@hP600:~$

joel@hP600:~$ LANG=C aplay -L | grep -A 1 default
default Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
--
sysdefault:CARD=PCH HDA Intel PCH, CX20952 Analog 
joel@hP600:~$

joel@hP600:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i -E "pulse|pipewi"
ii  gstreamer1.0-pipewire:amd64              0.3.65-3                             amd64        GStreamer 1.0 plugin for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-0:amd64                  0.3.65-3                             amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-common                   0.3.65-3                             all          libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - common files
ii  libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64            0.3.65-3                             amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - modules
ii  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64            16.1+dfsg1-2+b1                      amd64        PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)
ii  libpulse0:amd64                          16.1+dfsg1-2+b1                      amd64        PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulsedsp:amd64                        16.1+dfsg1-2+b1                      amd64        PulseAudio OSS pre-load library
ii  libspa-0.2-bluetooth:amd64               0.3.65-3                             amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - bluetooth plugins
ii  libspa-0.2-modules:amd64                 0.3.65-3                             amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server Simple Plugin API - modules
ii  pavucontrol                              5.0-2                                amd64        PulseAudio Volume Control
ii  pipewire:amd64                           0.3.65-3                             amd64        audio and video processing engine multimedia server
ii  pipewire-alsa:amd64                      0.3.65-3                             amd64        PipeWire ALSA plugin
ii  pipewire-audio                           0.3.65-3                             all          recommended set of PipeWire packages for a standard audio desktop use
ii  pipewire-audio-client-libraries          0.3.65-3                             all          transitional package for pipewire-alsa and pipewire-jack
ii  pipewire-bin                             0.3.65-3                             amd64        PipeWire multimedia server - programs
ii  pipewire-jack:amd64                      0.3.65-3                             amd64        PipeWire JACK plugin
ii  pipewire-pulse                           0.3.65-3                             amd64        PipeWire PulseAudio daemon
ii  pulseaudio-utils                         16.1+dfsg1-2+b1                      amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
ii  wireplumber                              0.4.13-1                             amd64        modular session / policy manager for PipeWire
ii  xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin:amd64            0.4.5-1                              amd64        Xfce4 panel plugin to control pulseaudio
joel@hP600:~$
```

Thanks for help